# How to construct a DateTimeOffset specific to a timezone?

Tags: c#

I need to construct a new DateTimeOffset instance with timezone. I know the exact day/hour/min, but I couldn't figure how the best way to get the last TimeSpan paramater:

```
var myTime = new DateTimeOffset(2023, 5, 7, 15, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(?,0,0));
```

I have the timezone id already, like "Pacific Standard Time". Just how do I get the TimeSpan value for any given timezone id? I don't want to manually enter any value as daylight saving time could alter the timespan values right?

This has to be a built-in function somewhere, I just couldn't find it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Only a time without the offset is not enough. When daylight saving changes we (here in germany) have the time `02:30:00` two times, one with `+01:00` and one with `+02:00`. But with only given `02:30:00` you can not say which one it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/instantiating-a-datetimeoffset-object#datetimeoffset-constructors), you can use `TimeZoneInfo`:

```cs
DateTime sourceDate = new DateTime(2023, 5, 7, 15, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
string timeZoneName = "Pacific Standard Time";
TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName)
    .GetUtcOffset(sourceDate);
var targetTime = new DateTimeOffset(2023, 5, 7, 15, 0, 0, offset);
Console.WriteLine(targetTime);
```

Comment: That will not work in all cases. The timespan switching from/to daylight saving is a problem with this solution

Comment: Sir Rufo, I think this solution works. The GetUtcOffset() already takes dst time into consideration.